# HTML error in Google Apps Script for EVE Online

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am currently working on a little recreational Google Apps Script (GAS) for EVE Online and I have hit a brick wall when I am getting my server side functions talking to my client side ones.
HTML:

```
<form id="frm1" name = "mat_add">
<input width="1000" type="text" name="mat" value="Enter Item Here"><br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="mat_sub" onclick= "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).shortlist(this.parentNode,document.getElementById('spn1').innerHTML)">
</form>
<span id="spn1"><table><tr><td>Type Name</td><td>Type ID</td></tr></table></span>

<script>
function onSuccess(output) {
  document.getElementById(output[0]).innerHTML = output[1];
};
</script>
```

GAS:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('UMX Web App');
};


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};


function shortlist(form,table) {
  var arr = transpose(htmlToArray(table));
  var item = form.mat;
  if ( isNaN(item) ) {
    var url = 'https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/api/typeid2.php?format=xml&typename=' + item.toString();
  } else {
    var url = 'https://api.eveonline.com/eve/TypeName.xml.aspx?ids=' + item.toString();
  };
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var name = document.getRootElement().getChild('result').getChild('rowset').getChild('row').getAttribute('typeName').getValue();
  if ( arr[0].indexOf(name) == -1 && name != 'Unknown Type' && name != 'bad item' ) {
    arr[0].push(name);
    arr[1].push(document.getRootElement().getChild('result').getChild('rowset').getChild('row').getAttribute('typeID').getValue());
  };
  var str = arrayToHTML(transpose(arr));
  return ['spn1',str]
};


function arrayToHTML(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var str = '<table>';
  while ( i < arr.length ) {
    str = str + '<tr>';
    while ( j < arr[i].length ) {
      str = str + '<td>' + arr[i][j] + '</td>';
      j += 1
    };
    str = str + '</tr>';
    j = 0;
    i += 1
  };
  str = str + '</table>';
  return str
};


function htmlToArray(str) {
  var arr1 = str.replace(/<tr>/g,'</tr>').split('</tr>');
  var arr2 = [];
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;
  var x = [];
  while ( i < arr1.length ) {
    arr2.push([]);
    x = arr1[i].replace(/<td>/g,'</td>').split('</td>');
    while ( j < x.length ) {
      arr2[arr2.length - 1].push(x[j]);
      j += 2
    };
    j = 1;
    i += 2
  };
  return arr2
};


function transpose(input) {
  var output = [];
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while ( i < input[0].length ) {
    output.push([]);
    while ( j < input.length ) {
      output[i].push(input[j][i]);
      j += 1
    };
    j = 0;
    i += 1
  };
  return output
};

function direct(input) {
  return input
}
```

The problem seems to be on the submit button because everything else is working fine.  I have been looking for a workaround but that submit button is the only point of entry I can get and it will not accept more than one variable.

Comment: What result are you seeing? What do you expect? Why have you concluded that the problem is on the submit button? Please add some more information.  One oddity - you call `shortlist` from the client with 2 parameters (`this.parentNode` and a string), but the server side treats a single `input` parameter as an array.

Comment: Sorry, I am expecting the result to be the table within "spn1" to add the new item but not if it is an error item or already in the table.  I don't think you can have a database in a GAS web app aside from a spreadsheet and that would cause problems if two people are using it at the same time so I was hoping I could get it by just scraping the innerHTML of this table and appending it.  The result I am getting is no response but just let me check with a failure handler... and nothing.  It isn't even giving me an error. Also I made a mistake in the original code, didn't press undo enough. fixed.

Comment: Check your client side javascript console - there will be an error about the parameters being passed to the server. When a `form` is a parameter, it must be the only parameter. You won't be able to pass the table like this. You could have the clickHandler build an object with form field + table, though. Better, you could put the script into a spreadsheet, and use IT as a database. Or you could use a hosted db...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem seems to be on the submit button because everything else is working fine. I have been looking for a workaround but that submit button is the only point of entry I can get and it will not accept more than one variable.

Let's focus on this, and ignore all the irrelevant code. Basic question: how to get multiple inputs from a form to a server-side GAS function?

This example will demonstrate communication of the form object to the server, by throwing an error that contains all the received parameters. An `errorHandler` on the client side will `alert` with the received error message.

#### Index.html

```
<form id="frm1" name = "mat_add">
  <input width="1000" type="text" name="mat" placeholder="Enter Item Here" /><br />
  <input width="1000" type="text" name="mat2" placeholder="Enter Quantity Here" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" name="mat_sub" onclick="google.script.run
                                                                           .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
                                                                           .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
                                                                           .shortlist(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

<script>
function onSuccess(output) {
  document.getElementById(output[0]).innerHTML = output[1];
};

function onFailure(error) {
  alert( error.message );
}
</script>
```

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('UMX Web App');
};

function shortlist(input) {
  reportErr(JSON.stringify(input,null,2))
}

function reportErr(msg) {
  throw new Error( msg );
}
```

Run this webapp, and here's your result:

[image: screenshot]

The two named `input` elements, `mat` and `mat2` were communicated to the server function `shortlist()` via the `this.parent` parameter. Since the button invoking `this.parent` in its clickHandler is contained in the `frm1` form, all input elements of that form were included, and may be referenced on the server side as **named properties** of the `input` parameter of `shortlist()`. (NOT as array elements.)

The upshot of this is that your `shortlist()` function can be modified thusly:

```
function shortlist(input) {
  var item = input.mat;
  if ( isNaN(item) ) {
    var url = 'https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/api/typeid2.php?format=xml&typename=' + item;
  } else {
    var url = 'https://api.eveonline.com/eve/TypeName.xml.aspx?ids=' + item.toString();
  };
  ...
```